# Common column between two tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am writing an android app that has two tables:

```
String createQuery1 =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_TRIP + " (" + IDTRIP_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                                     + DATE_COLUMN + " TEXT)";


    String createQuery2 =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_GPS + " (" + IDGPS_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                                    + ID_TRIP_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "
                                                    + DISTANCE_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, "
                                                    + LATITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL, "
                                                    + LONGITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL)";
```

I want *ID_TRIP* from the second table to always have the same value as IDTRIP from the first table.

is it possible to link the two columns so that they are always the same?

The goal should be the following;

```
Table Trip                        Table GPS

Trip     Date                     ID    Trip    distance   ...
  1      xxx                      1      1        xxx
  2      xxx                      2      1        xxx
  3      xxx                      3      1        xxx
                                  4      2        xxx
                                  5      2        xxx
                                  6      3        xxx
```

The trip is increased by a button click, and the GPS data comes automatically every x seconds. Now I would like the GPS data to be mapped to the current trip by also incrementing the *TRIP_ID* column in the GPS table when the button is clicked.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by "always have the same value?"  Can you show us sample data?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, by using a so called **trigger**. Whenever a value in that column changes in table A, the corresponding value it will be updated in table B. You'll have to provide a way (unique identifier) to identify the specific row the column belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have constrain.(I hope this is what you are looking for)

```
String createQuery2 =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_GPS + " (" + IDGPS_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                                + ID_TRIP_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "
                                                + DISTANCE_COLUMN + " INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, "
                                                + LATITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL, "
                                                + LONGITUDE_COLUMN + " REAL DEFAULT NULL,"
                        + "CONSTRAINT TRP FOREIGN KEY ( " + ID_TRIP_COLUMN + ")"
                        + "REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME_TRIP + "(" + IDTRIP_COLUMN +")";
```

Comment: @Robotz91 This constraint prevents you from writing a wrong value. But the database does not know *which* trip you want to use, so you still have to insert it.

Comment: `automated`... that's why I suggested to create a **trigger**.